# Index on mysql partitioned tables

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, partition

I have a table with two partitions. Partitions are `pactive = 1` and `pinactive = 0`. I understand that two partitions does not make so much of a gain, but I have used it to truncate and load in one partition and plain inserts in another partition.

The problem comes when I create indexes.

Query goes this way

```
select partitionflag,companyid,activityname
from customformattributes
where companyid=47
      and activityname = 'Activity 1'
      and partitionflag=0
```

Created index  -

```
create index idx_try on customformattributes(partitionflag,companyid,activityname,completiondate,attributename,isclosed)
```

there are around 200000 records that will be retreived from the above query. But the query along with the mentioned index takes 30+ seconds. What is the reason for such a long time? Also, if remove the partitionflag from the mentioned index, the index is not even used.

And is the understanding that,

1. Even with the partitions available, the optimizer needs to have the required partition mentioned in the index definition, so that it only hits the required partition ---- Correct?

Any ideas on understanding this would be very helpful

Comment: Without an explain output, all we can do is to guess.

Comment: Hi, please find below the plan details

id - 1
select_type - SIMPLE
table - customformattributes
type - ref
possible_keys - idx_try
key - idx_try
key_len - 213
ref - const, const, const
rows - 247892
filtered - 100.00
Extra - Using where; Using index

Comment: I do not think that there is anything particularly wrong with the query execution plan. You have a big resultset. Have you tried reducing the resultset and check the query performance that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your index by reordering the columns in it. Usually the columns in the index are ordered by its cardinality (starting from the highest and go down to the lowest). Cardinality is the uniqueness of data in the given column. So in your case I suppose there are many variations of companyid in customformattributes table while partitionflag will have cardinality of 2 (if all the options for this column are 1 and 0).
Your query will first filter all the rows with partitionflag=0, then it will filter by company id and so on.
When you remove partitionflag from the index the query did not used the index because may be the optimizer decides that it will be faster to make full table scan instead of using the index (in most of the cases the optimizer is right)

For the given query:

```
select partitionflag,companyid,activityname
from customformattributes
where companyid=47
  and activityname = 'Activity 1'
  and partitionflag=0
```

the following index may be would be better (but of course :

```
create index idx_try on customformattributes(companyid,activityname, completiondate,attributename, partitionflag, isclosed)
```

For the query to use index the following rule must be met - the left most column in the index should be present in the where clause ... and depending on the mysql version you are using additional query requirements may be needed. For example if you are using old version of mysql - you may need to order the columns in the where clause in the same order they are listed in the index. In the last versions of mysql the query optimizer is responsible for ordering the columns in the where clause in the correct order.

Your SELECT query took 30+ seconds because it returns 200k rows and because the index might not be the optimal for the given query.

For the second question about the partitioning: the common rule is that the column you are partitioning by must be part of all the **UNIQUE** keys in a table (Primary key is also unique key by definition so the column should be added to the PK also). If table structure and logic allows you to add the partitioning column to all the **UNIQUE** indexes in the table then you add it and partition the table.
When the partitioning is made correctly you can take the advantage of partitioning pruning - this is when SELECT query searches the data only in the partitions where given data is stored (otherwise it looks in all partitions)

You can read more about partitioning here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response.. your explanation helped me understand indexes better .. Thanks !!

Comment: I hope it helped you solve the problem with the query.

Comment: Can you accept one of the answers (if you are OK with it) so the question not remain unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

The query is slow simply because disks are slow.

Cardinality is not important when designing an index.

The optimal index for *that* query is

```
INDEX(companyid, activityname, partitionflag)  -- in any order
```

It is "covering" since it includes *all* the columns mentioned anywhere in the `SELECT`.  This is indicated by "Using index" in the `EXPLAIN`.

Leaving off the other 3 columns makes the query faster because it will have to read less off the disk.

If you make *any* changes to the query (add columns, change from '=' to '>', add `ORDER BY`, etc), then the index may no longer be optimal.

"Also, if remove the partitionflag from the mentioned index, the index is not even used." -- That is because it was no longer "covering".

Keep in mind that there are two ways an index may be used -- "covering" versus being a way to look up the data.  When you don't have a "covering" index, the optimizer chooses between using the index and bouncing between the index and the data versus simply ignoring the index and scanning the table.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response.. your explanation helped me understand indexes better .. Thanks !!